# What does $n\gg 0$ mean in abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I am reading [this book's](http://books.google.com/books?id=BdAbcje-TZUC&lpg=PR9&ots=ivJAgBUZdY&dq=polynomial%20rings%20concrete%20abstract%20algebra&pg=PA144#v=onepage&q=polynomial%20rings%20&f=false) page 144.

While defining polynomial rings the author uses notation $n\gg 0$. I know that it means very very greater than but in this context it doesn't seem to mean that.

What does it mean in this context?

Thank you!

Comment: It does mean the same thing; here $f$ will be the function giving the coefficient of the polynomials, i.e the final function will be of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) X^n$. The condition you mention is that only finitely many coefficients are non-zero.

Comment: @ClementC. I see. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "for $n$ sufficiently large". For example, in this context, there exists $N>0$ so that for $n>N$, $f(n)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to mean '' there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $f(n)=0$ for $n \geq N$ ''. This is usually written '' for $n$ large enough '', I don't believe this notation is standard.